# Cannot access $(document).ready() code after $.ajax call

Tags: jquery

I have a link "Go fullscreen" in the footer of every page. In document.ready(), I have a code that needs to be executed on clicking this link. There are two other links that fetch content from next and previous pages on this page via $.ajax call. The content loads alright, but once the ajax call is processed, the 'go fullscreen' link stops working. Essentially, its click event in the document.ready() is not called. How to make a code that lies in document.ready() always work even after an ajax call.

Code

```
$.ajax({
    url: $j('#prev a').attr('href'),
    success: function(data) {
                data=$j(data).find('.container > .row');
                $j('.container').html(data);
                $j("#go-fullscreen").bind('click');
             }
    });
```

Comment: Why do you use `$.ajax` but `$j("selector")`? What's the difference between `$` and `$j`?

Comment: $j is just for jquery no-conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this;

```
$j("#go-fullscreen").bind('click');
```

You aren't binding to any particular event handler function, therefore nothing happens on the click.  You need to specify the function you want to execute upon the click.   See the [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) for details.

```
$j("#go-fullscreen").bind('click', function() { /* your code here */});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't post any code at all, I'm making some assumptions.  Sounds like you're dynamically loading/changing the footer content.  Also sounds like you're wiring up the click using something like:

`$('a').click(function() { //... });`

If this is all true, you want to change how you're wiring up the event.  Look into [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

`$('.container').on('click', '#go-fullscreen', function() { //... });`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will look in to '.on'. I have added my code.

Comment: Can you also post the HTML markup on the page?  Also, you're using .bind, but not giving it a callback at all.

Comment: Yes, the data of the whole '.container' which includes almost everything on the page gets changed on ajax call.

Comment: Cool, I updated my .on in my answer to use the classes and ids you're using.  Try that out, should do everything you need.  Obviously, you'll need to put your click event code inside the function in my example.

Comment: I really tried clicking both answers as correct answers, trust me! But stack overflow doesnt let me. THIS IS A MANUAL THUMBS UP FOR ANOTHER CORRECT ANSWER BY GROMER!